# Name for the line equidistant to three mutually orthogonal planes

Tags: geometry

I have a doubt on the name of a geometric quantity.

Say I have three mutually orthogonal planes (like forming a corner). I want to know the name of the line of points which are equidistant to those three planes. I know it is as well the intersection of the three bisectors, one for each pair of planes.

Comment: Up to my knowledge, there is no name for it. Calling it a bisecting line would be abnormal because it does not divide anything in 2 parts as should be indicated by prefix "bi".

Comment: This looks like a special case of [equidistant set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistant_set), I'll probably just call it equidistant lines (the equidistant set for 3 planes is the union of 3 lines).

Comment: There are four such lines. I'd call them symmetry lines or space diagonals.